# Return the sum of values from a column (C) when conditions are meet in both Column B and Column A

Tags: vba

Sorry if the title is confusing... its hard to title what I am trying to do and would like to use VBA to help with the following.

I have a table of lenders and borrowers. 3 individuals (Alex, Bill & Charlie) lend and borrow money from each other and my table shows each transaction made:

[image: Table]

I want to sum all the values for each of the possible combinations and return a single value for each combination which shows who owes who money and how much:

[image: Table showing totals]

And then based on this show who owes who and how much they owe... so in the above example Charlie owes Bill $434, but Bill owes Charlie $48 so Charlie only owes bill $386:

[image: final amount owing]

Is this possible... I can do it manually using If Statements and hide the formula rows etc.. and its not too bad with 3 people (6 combinations), but if I add a fourth person it would be 24 combinations, so I am looking for an easier way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This can be done purely with SQL but there is an obvious problem with your data structure - what if two people share a name?

Comment: Step one, combining matching Lender/Borrower permutations, is just a matter of slapping it into a PivotTable.

Comment: Thanks Martin - in the real life data I will be using i will have unique identifiers not names

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with formulae:

The following are the column formulae:

```
A: Lender
B: Borrower
C: Amount
D/E: =UNIQUE(A:B)
F: =D1&"-"&E1 
G: =SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,D1,B:B,E1)
H: =E1&"-"&D1
I: =XLOOKUP(H1,F:F,G:G,0)
J: =IF(K1<>"",E1&" owes "&D1,"")
K: =IF(G1-I1>0,G1-I1,"")
L: =K1<>""
M: =FILTER(J:K,L:L)
```

Columns F though L should be filled down at least long enough to cover the possible combinations of Lender and Borrower. You can fill down way further than needed - extra rows are ignored.

Then, hide all columns except A, B, C, M and N.

[image: sample]

Comment: That should work andrew, and cleaner than what I was doing, thanks